# Maximize screen space in GoodNotes 6

Tags: goodnotes-app

I’m starting to use GoodNotes 6. In the old version I recall my document page taking the entire screen, with a floating tool bar on the side.

In the new version much of the screen real estate is taken by tabs (for documents), a large tool bar mostly empty, and then another tool bar with drawing tools. This adds up to a terrible waste of space on an iPad.

Is there some way to kill the tabs, and get back to a minimal floating tool bar.

Comment: That appears to be a purchased product.  Have you asked their support?

Comment: On many applications, F11 or F12 toggles the full-screen interface. Though i have no idea if that works in GoodNotes, it's worth a try (when you're not in the middle of editing a critical document ;-).